# Composer does not load more 6 packages

Tags: magento, composer-php, magento2

I have a problem with composer. Try to install magento 2 (or reinstall). Composer loads only 6 packages and stops every time.
https://content.screencast.com/users/Torys87/folders/Jing/media/33f9f1ae-bb3f-4f09-a9fe-5cd821a14b31/2017-11-01_1526.png

Does not matter downloading or load from cache.
Could anyone help with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to install the packages globally? I'd try a local install first (so the packages install to `magento_root\vendor`). If that still doesn't work, then I'd get composer.phar and run `php composer.phar install` from the magento root. If that works, then it probably means you need to reinstall composer.

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work. I try to install local from magento dir and using composer.phar